# android intent acts diffrent according to time

Tags: java, android, android-intent

i have a program that runs 1 activity that passed to another that passed to another for some reason if i pass second to third right away it works but if i pass it over time and i mean the second runs for a minute or so and then pass to the third with the same code just a limitation of time it opens the third for few seconds then close it and i cant understand why it closes it cause i use the same code please i beg for help

```
Intent MainIntent = new Intent(v.getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        MainIntent.putExtra("text", text);
        finish();
        startActivity(MainIntent);


>     11-17 21:26:12.041: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 5737(231KB) AllocSpace objects, 72(1800KB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.100ms total 169.371ms
>     11-17 21:26:13.231: I/art(1629): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 904(35KB) AllocSpace objects, 74(1850KB) LOS objects,
> 6% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.173ms total 127.113ms
>     11-17 21:26:14.291: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1967(88KB) AllocSpace objects, 76(1900KB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.036ms total 151.703ms
>     11-17 21:26:16.461: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1716(72KB) AllocSpace objects, 79(1975KB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.049ms total 141.209ms
>     11-17 21:26:22.061: I/art(1629): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2786(108KB) AllocSpace objects, 63(1575KB) LOS objects,
> 6% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.033ms total 114.257ms
>     11-17 21:26:23.921: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2249(96KB) AllocSpace objects, 78(1950KB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 4.189ms total 199.602ms
>     11-17 21:26:28.026: I/UsageStatsService(345): User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
>     11-17 21:26:35.341: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1762(80KB) AllocSpace objects, 87(2MB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 8.192ms total 139.474ms
>     11-17 21:26:39.613: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1530(64KB) AllocSpace objects, 78(1950KB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.625ms total 130.211ms
>     11-17 21:26:39.616: I/art(1629): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 13.988ms for cause HeapTrim
>     11-17 21:26:45.540: I/Choreographer(1629): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:26:49.231: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1642(74KB) AllocSpace objects, 80(2000KB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.533ms total 125.101ms
>     11-17 21:26:50.932: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1579(66KB) AllocSpace objects, 77(1925KB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.212ms total 130.842ms
>     11-17 21:26:51.891: I/art(1629): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 749(29KB) AllocSpace objects, 63(1575KB) LOS objects,
> 6% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.100ms total 108.809ms
>     11-17 21:26:52.722: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1586(67KB) AllocSpace objects, 80(2000KB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.025ms total 120.697ms
>     11-17 21:26:57.172: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1959(83KB) AllocSpace objects, 82(2MB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.028ms total 131.430ms
>     11-17 21:27:00.193: I/Choreographer(1629): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:27:04.802: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 3887(159KB) AllocSpace objects, 76(1900KB) LOS
> objects, 7% free, 26MB/28MB, paused 1.185ms total 112.872ms
>     11-17 21:27:10.545: I/ActivityManager(345): START u0 {cmp=self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.savewords} from uid 10054 on display 0
>     11-17 21:27:10.881: E/MediaPlayer(1629): Should have subtitle controller already set
>     11-17 21:27:10.884: I/whatreaded(1629): 29
>     11-17 21:27:11.011: I/art(1629): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1432(81KB) AllocSpace objects, 41(1016KB) LOS objects,
> 4% free, 27MB/28MB, paused 1.030ms total 107.062ms
>     11-17 21:27:11.366: E/MediaPlayer(1629): Should have subtitle controller already set
>     11-17 21:27:13.844: I/art(345): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 4102(267KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(80KB) LOS objects, 5%
> free, 8MB/8MB, paused 42.380ms total 283.133ms
>     11-17 21:27:14.454: I/Choreographer(1629): Skipped 750 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:27:15.617: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 48 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:27:15.643: I/ActivityManager(345): Displayed self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.savewords: +5s57ms
>     11-17 21:27:30.848: I/ActivityManager(345): START u0 {cmp=self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.discoverstring} from uid 10054 on
> display 0
>     11-17 21:27:31.138: E/MediaPlayer(1629): Should have subtitle controller already set
>     11-17 21:27:35.098: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): start(0xb5a3d200)
>     11-17 21:27:35.101: I/GenericSource(66): start
>     11-17 21:27:35.133: E/MediaPlayer(1629): Should have subtitle controller already set
>     11-17 21:27:35.281: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 38(1592B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects,
> 5% free, 35MB/37MB, paused 1.252ms total 181.547ms
>     11-17 21:27:35.308: D/AudioSink(66): bufferCount (8) is too small and increased to 12
>     11-17 21:27:35.416: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 39 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:27:35.748: I/Choreographer(1629): Skipped 148 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:27:36.119: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:27:36.628: I/art(1629): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 116(4KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0%
> free, 38MB/38MB, paused 2.632ms total 198.464ms
>     11-17 21:27:38.994: I/ActivityManager(345): Displayed self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.discoverstring: +8s74ms
>     11-17 21:27:44.236: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 328(15KB) AllocSpace objects, 42(1050KB) LOS
> objects, 4% free, 42MB/44MB, paused 998us total 164.972ms
>     11-17 21:27:55.462: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 328(14KB) AllocSpace objects, 79(1975KB) LOS
> objects, 4% free, 42MB/44MB, paused 1.312ms total 207.378ms
>     11-17 21:28:01.113: I/art(1629): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 79(4KB) AllocSpace objects, 78(1950KB) LOS objects, 4%
> free, 42MB/44MB, paused 987us total 128.269ms
>     11-17 21:28:06.901: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 398(17KB) AllocSpace objects, 79(1975KB) LOS
> objects, 4% free, 42MB/44MB, paused 1.044ms total 169.931ms
>     11-17 21:28:10.368: I/Choreographer(1629): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:28:12.347: I/art(1629): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 83(5KB) AllocSpace objects, 77(1925KB) LOS objects, 4%
> free, 42MB/44MB, paused 19.686ms total 155.656ms
>     11-17 21:28:17.517: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 398(17KB) AllocSpace objects, 80(2000KB) LOS
> objects, 4% free, 42MB/44MB, paused 961us total 293.048ms
>     11-17 21:28:22.067: I/art(1629): Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 79(4KB) AllocSpace objects, 79(1975KB) LOS objects, 4%
> free, 42MB/44MB, paused 970us total 121.016ms
>     11-17 21:28:23.034: I/ActivityManager(345): START u0 {cmp=self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.learningword (has extras)} from uid
> 10054 on display 0
>     11-17 21:28:23.604: E/MediaPlayer(1629): Should have subtitle controller already set
>     11-17 21:28:24.222: I/art(345): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 19034(1145KB) AllocSpace objects, 6(212KB) LOS objects,
> 19% free, 7MB/8MB, paused 2.839ms total 1.167s
>     11-17 21:28:24.741: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 450(20KB) AllocSpace objects, 18(450KB) LOS
> objects, 4% free, 45MB/47MB, paused 5.531ms total 107.503ms
>     11-17 21:28:25.643: I/art(1629): Clamp target GC heap from 49MB to 48MB
>     11-17 21:28:25.643: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 58(2368B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects,
> 0% free, 47MB/48MB, paused 25.825ms total 118.202ms
>     11-17 21:28:26.351: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): start(0xb5a5d480)
>     11-17 21:28:26.359: I/GenericSource(66): start
>     11-17 21:28:26.456: D/AudioSink(66): bufferCount (8) is too small and increased to 12
>     11-17 21:28:26.607: E/MediaPlayer(1629): Should have subtitle controller already set
>     11-17 21:28:26.607: I/Choreographer(1629): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:28:28.409: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:28:28.557: I/temp(1629): 24
>     11-17 21:28:28.671: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 31 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:28:28.722: I/Choreographer(1629): Skipped 515 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:28:29.599: I/art(1629): Clamp target GC heap from 49MB to 48MB
>     11-17 21:28:29.789: I/art(1629): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 8.408ms for cause Alloc
>     11-17 21:28:29.852: I/art(1629): Clamp target GC heap from 49MB to 48MB
>     11-17 21:28:29.852: I/art(1629): Alloc partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 13(464B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0%
> free, 47MB/48MB, paused 1.155ms total 60.435ms
>     11-17 21:28:29.871: I/art(1629): Alloc sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 0(0B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free,
> 47MB/48MB, paused 1.158ms total 16.049ms
>     11-17 21:28:29.940: I/art(1629): Clamp target GC heap from 49MB to 48MB
>     11-17 21:28:29.941: I/art(1629): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(12KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free,
> 47MB/48MB, paused 1.135ms total 64.586ms
>     11-17 21:28:29.941: I/art(1629): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 96KB allocation
>     11-17 21:28:30.034: I/art(1629): Clamp target GC heap from 49MB to 48MB
>     11-17 21:28:30.034: I/art(1629): Alloc concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11(344B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free,
> 47MB/48MB, paused 1.123ms total 91.717ms
>     11-17 21:28:30.034: E/art(1629): Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 99012 byte allocation with 67972 free bytes and 66KB
> until OOM"
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-179
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629): Process: self.yanfaingold.talkgame, PID: 1629
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 99012 byte allocation
> with 67972 free bytes and 66KB until OOM
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):   at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:817)
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:794)
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:714)
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:639)
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):   at self.yanfaingold.talkgame.learningword$OurView.createbitmaps(learningword.java:252)
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):   at self.yanfaingold.talkgame.learningword$OurView.run(learningword.java:164)
>     11-17 21:28:30.043: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
>     11-17 21:28:30.063: W/ActivityManager(345):   Force finishing activity self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.learningword
>     11-17 21:28:30.076: W/ActivityManager(345):   Force finishing activity self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.discoverstring
>     11-17 21:28:30.382: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 36 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:28:30.727: W/ActivityManager(345): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{3cf145b6 u0 self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.learningword
> t8 f}
>     11-17 21:28:31.609: I/art(1629): Clamp target GC heap from 49MB to 48MB
>     11-17 21:28:31.609: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 17(672B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0%
> free, 47MB/48MB, paused 1.191ms total 101.395ms
>     11-17 21:28:32.344: I/art(1629): Clamp target GC heap from 49MB to 48MB
>     11-17 21:28:32.344: I/art(1629): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 8(256B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0%
> free, 47MB/48MB, paused 1.112ms total 184.826ms
>     11-17 21:28:33.039: W/ActivityManager(345): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
>     11-17 21:28:43.116: W/ActivityManager(345): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{3f2adb63 u0
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.discoverstring t8 f}
>     11-17 21:28:43.289: W/ActivityManager(345): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{3cf145b6 u0
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.learningword t8 f}
>     11-17 21:29:20.815: D/LightsService(345): Excessive delay setting light: 65ms
>     11-17 21:29:21.000: D/LightsService(345): Excessive delay setting light: 62ms
>     11-17 21:29:21.283: W/AudioTrack(345): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
>     11-17 21:29:21.444: I/Process(1629): Sending signal. PID: 1629 SIG: 9
>     11-17 21:29:21.496: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:21.974: I/WindowState(345): WIN DEATH: Window{c9dd348 u0 self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.savewords}
>     11-17 21:29:21.974: W/WindowManager(345): Force-removing child win Window{29adcaf0 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{c9dd348 u0
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.savewords}
>     11-17 21:29:21.984: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): reset(0xb5a3d280)
>     11-17 21:29:21.997: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): notifyResetComplete(0xb5a3d280)
>     11-17 21:29:22.002: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): reset(0xb5a3d300)
>     11-17 21:29:22.015: W/InputDispatcher(345): channel '147325da self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.savewords
> (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. 
> events=0x9
>     11-17 21:29:22.016: E/InputDispatcher(345): channel '147325da self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.savewords
> (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>     11-17 21:29:22.019: W/InputDispatcher(345): channel '2ffac0ad self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.learningword
> (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. 
> events=0x9
>     11-17 21:29:22.019: E/InputDispatcher(345): channel '2ffac0ad self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.learningword
> (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>     11-17 21:29:22.026: W/InputDispatcher(345): channel '53de37e self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.discoverstring
> (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. 
> events=0x9
>     11-17 21:29:22.027: E/InputDispatcher(345): channel '53de37e self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.discoverstring
> (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
>     11-17 21:29:22.034: I/ActivityManager(345): Process self.yanfaingold.talkgame (pid 1629) has died
>     11-17 21:29:22.059: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): notifyResetComplete(0xb5a3d300)
>     11-17 21:29:22.063: W/AudioFlinger(66): session id 75 not found for pid 1629
>     11-17 21:29:22.063: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): reset(0xb5a4e180)
>     11-17 21:29:22.113: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): notifyResetComplete(0xb5a4e180)
>     11-17 21:29:22.117: W/AudioFlinger(66): session id 77 not found for pid 1629
>     11-17 21:29:22.117: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): reset(0xb5a5d400)
>     11-17 21:29:22.123: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): notifyResetComplete(0xb5a5d400)
>     11-17 21:29:22.127: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): reset(0xb5a3d200)
>     11-17 21:29:22.150: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): notifyResetComplete(0xb5a3d200)
>     11-17 21:29:22.152: W/AudioFlinger(66): session id 81 not found for pid 1629
>     11-17 21:29:22.153: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): reset(0xb5a5d480)
>     11-17 21:29:22.193: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): notifyResetComplete(0xb5a5d480)
>     11-17 21:29:22.198: W/AudioFlinger(66): session id 83 not found for pid 1629
>     11-17 21:29:22.240: I/WindowState(345): WIN DEATH: Window{2ffac0ad u0 self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.learningword}
>     11-17 21:29:22.240: W/InputDispatcher(345): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '2ffac0ad
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.learningword
> (server)'
>     11-17 21:29:22.241: W/WindowManager(345): Force-removing child win Window{1874b869 u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{2ffac0ad u0
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.learningword}
>     11-17 21:29:22.280: W/WindowManager(345): Failed looking up window
>     11-17 21:29:22.280: W/WindowManager(345): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window
> android.os.BinderProxy@746efe2 does not exist
>     11-17 21:29:22.280: W/WindowManager(345):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8409)
>     11-17 21:29:22.280: W/WindowManager(345):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8400)
>     11-17 21:29:22.280: W/WindowManager(345):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1113)
>     11-17 21:29:22.280: W/WindowManager(345):     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:534)
>     11-17 21:29:22.280: I/WindowState(345): WIN DEATH: null
>     11-17 21:29:22.286: I/WindowState(345): WIN DEATH: Window{147325da u0 self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.savewords}
>     11-17 21:29:22.286: W/InputDispatcher(345): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '147325da
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.savewords
> (server)'
>     11-17 21:29:22.287: W/WindowManager(345): Force-removing child win Window{418b2ee u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{147325da u0
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.savewords}
>     11-17 21:29:22.322: W/WindowManager(345): Failed looking up window
>     11-17 21:29:22.322: W/WindowManager(345): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window
> android.os.BinderProxy@2b2bba0b does not exist
>     11-17 21:29:22.322: W/WindowManager(345):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8409)
>     11-17 21:29:22.322: W/WindowManager(345):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8400)
>     11-17 21:29:22.322: W/WindowManager(345):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1113)
>     11-17 21:29:22.322: W/WindowManager(345):     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:534)
>     11-17 21:29:22.322: I/WindowState(345): WIN DEATH: null
>     11-17 21:29:22.325: I/WindowState(345): WIN DEATH: Window{53de37e u0 self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.discoverstring}
>     11-17 21:29:22.326: W/InputDispatcher(345): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '53de37e
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.discoverstring
> (server)'
>     11-17 21:29:22.329: W/WindowManager(345): Force-removing child win Window{171ce38f u0 SurfaceView} from container Window{53de37e u0
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.discoverstring}
>     11-17 21:29:22.367: W/WindowManager(345): Failed looking up window
>     11-17 21:29:22.367: W/WindowManager(345): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window
> android.os.BinderProxy@3de93418 does not exist
>     11-17 21:29:22.367: W/WindowManager(345):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8409)
>     11-17 21:29:22.367: W/WindowManager(345):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:8400)
>     11-17 21:29:22.367: W/WindowManager(345):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1113)
>     11-17 21:29:22.367: W/WindowManager(345):     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:534)
>     11-17 21:29:22.367: I/WindowState(345): WIN DEATH: null
>     11-17 21:29:22.508: I/art(69): Background concurrent mark sweep GC freed 793(33KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 82% free,
> 111KB/623KB, paused 11.012ms total 84.867ms
>     11-17 21:29:22.572: I/ActivityManager(345): Start proc self.yanfaingold.talkgame for activity
> self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.savewords: pid=1688 uid=10054 gids={50054,
> 9997} abi=armeabi-v7a
>     11-17 21:29:22.666: I/art(1688): Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
>     11-17 21:29:22.986: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 32 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:23.448: E/MediaPlayer(1688): Should have subtitle controller already set
>     11-17 21:29:23.457: I/whatreaded(1688): 29
>     11-17 21:29:23.715: E/MediaPlayer(1688): Should have subtitle controller already set
>     11-17 21:29:23.799: I/art(1688): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 97(17KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects,
> 38% free, 828KB/1340KB, paused 5.563ms total 149.738ms
>     11-17 21:29:24.043: I/Choreographer(1688): Skipped 77 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:24.114: D/gralloc_goldfish(1688): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>     11-17 21:29:24.191: W/art(1688): Suspending all threads took: 10.220ms
>     11-17 21:29:24.212: I/art(1688): Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 41(1504B) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects,
> 24% free, 2MB/2MB, paused 12.127ms total 47.030ms
>     11-17 21:29:24.455: W/InputMethodManagerService(345): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1629 uid
> 10054
>     11-17 21:29:24.508: I/ActivityManager(345): Displayed self.yanfaingold.talkgame/.savewords: +2s136ms (total +1m1s420ms)
>     11-17 21:29:25.103: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 30 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:25.291: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 40 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:26.007: W/AudioTrack(345): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
>     11-17 21:29:26.196: W/ResourceType(416): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
>     11-17 21:29:26.196: W/PackageManager(416): Failure retrieving resources for self.yanfaingold.talkgame: Resource ID #0x0
>     11-17 21:29:26.346: I/ActivityManager(345): START u0 {act=com.android.systemui.recents.SHOW_RECENTS flg=0x10804000
> cmp=com.android.systemui/.recents.RecentsActivity (has extras)} from
> uid 10012 on display 0
>     11-17 21:29:26.399: D/gralloc(55): Registering a buffer in the process that created it. This may cause memory ordering problems.
>     11-17 21:29:26.400: E/libEGL(55): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
>     11-17 21:29:26.400: E/SurfaceFlinger(55): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 0
>     11-17 21:29:26.400: E/SurfaceFlinger(55): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
>     11-17 21:29:26.420: W/WindowManager(345): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (480x854) to layer 21020
>     11-17 21:29:26.420: E/ActivityManager(345): Invalid thumbnail dimensions: 288x288
>     11-17 21:29:26.702: I/Choreographer(416): Skipped 171 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:26.838: W/ResourceType(416): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000000
>     11-17 21:29:26.852: W/PackageManager(416): Failure retrieving resources for self.yanfaingold.talkgame: Resource ID #0x0
>     11-17 21:29:26.946: I/Choreographer(416): Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:27.446: I/Choreographer(416): Skipped 120 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:27.842: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:38.293: W/AudioTrack(345): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
>     11-17 21:29:38.942: I/ActivityManager(345): Killing 1688:self.yanfaingold.talkgame/u0a54 (adj 9): remove task
>     11-17 21:29:39.032: I/WindowState(345): WIN DEATH: Window{35c404e u0 self.yanfaingold.talkgame/self.yanfaingold.talkgame.savewords}
>     11-17 21:29:39.036: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): reset(0xb5a3d380)
>     11-17 21:29:39.045: D/NuPlayerDriver(66): notifyResetComplete(0xb5a3d380)
>     11-17 21:29:39.187: D/TaskPersister(345): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=8_task.xml
>     11-17 21:29:39.194: I/ActivityManager(345): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME]
> flg=0x10200000
> cmp=com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher} from uid
> 10012 on display 0
>     11-17 21:29:39.376: I/Choreographer(416): Skipped 127 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:39.722: I/art(657): WaitForGcToComplete blocked for 61.081ms for cause DisableMovingGc
>     11-17 21:29:39.943: I/Choreographer(657): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:44.432: I/Choreographer(345): Skipped 41 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:44.528: I/Choreographer(657): Skipped 1088 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
>     11-17 21:29:45.898: I/Choreographer(657): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: finish() close the activity, check in your code where u have put it

Comment: You need to finish the current activity, then create a new `Intent` to launch another `Activity`. In your case, it will be `MainActivity`.

Comment: Post logcat of the stacktrace - if it's closing then you're almost certainly getting an exception somewhere.

Comment: @learning: I don't have any experience with Android game development, so I'll delete my answer. Hopefully, someone else with game experience can help you. Sorry.

Comment: ok tnx its my 1st game mybe i doing it wrong but till now all activitys work but this bug with the intent not doing what i want i just cant get this

Comment: i removed the finish from 2nd activity and it seems to work i think i tryed it very odd if i start new activity it close current one? i doubt it no idea but if work better not touch i guess

Comment: You should post your logcat. This contains the runtime errors. You've posted the output of the compiler, which is showing a bunch of lint warnings, which are not relevant to your question.

Comment: also on avd and my htc one x it acts diffrently in avd it go 1->2->3->1->2->3(autoclose)pop error after press ok open 3 again ,in htc it go 1->2->3->1->2(autoclose) and open 2 again